# Removing original and duplicate value from list of lists based on single element

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I want to remove both the duplicate and original, if a duplicate exists in the first element:

```
x=[["1.2.3.4","thing1"], ["8.8.8.8","thing2"], ["8.8.8.8","thing3"], ["8.8.4.4","thing4"]]
```

So I would want the output to be:

```
[["1.2.3.4","thing1"], ["8.8.4.4","thing4"]]
```

I have tried the following:

```
print [a for a in x if x[0].count(a[0]) == 1]
```

However, I only get the first item:

```
[['1.2.3.4', 'DNS']]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I need to remove both the duplicate and the original value if a duplicate is found. Both "Most pythonic way to remove tuples from a list if first element is a duplicate" and "Removing duplicates from list of lists in Python" keep one of the duplicate values.
Thank you.

Comment: I need to remove both the duplicate and the original value if a duplicate is found. Both "Most pythonic way to remove tuples from a list if first element is a duplicate" and "Removing duplicates from list of lists in Python" keep one of the duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter([a[0] for a in x])
print([a for a in x if counts[a[0]]==1] )
#[['1.2.3.4', 'thing1'], ['8.8.4.4', 'thing4']]
```

First build a `Counter` to count the occurrences of the first element in each item of your list. Then filter your list and keep only the values where the count for that item is 1.